# Handling division by zero exception in average calculation for empty lists

Tags: list, function, kotlin, exception

I am trying to implement a function in Kotlin that returns the average of a list of numbers. The function should take a list of integers as an argument and return the average of all the elements in the list.

Here's what I have so far (with an example):

```kotlin
fun getAverage(nums: List<Int>): Double{
    return (nums.sum().toDouble() / nums.size)
}

val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val newList = getAverage(numbers)
```

This code works fine for lists with a non-zero number of elements, but it throws a division by zero exception for empty lists. How can I modify the function to handle empty lists gracefully and return a default value, such as 0, in that case?

> Keep in mind, I do not want a predefined function, I want to implement my own, so in the future I will be able to customize it as I please

Comment: What result do you want for empty lists?

Comment: I think that if its an empty list it should work as if the list is filled with zeros, a.k.a return the value 0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an `if` (In Kotlin, you can use `if`s as expressions yielding the last value):

```kotlin
fun getAverage(nums: List<Int>): Double{
    return
        if (nums.isEmpty())
            0.0
        else
            (nums.sum().toDouble() / nums.size)
}
```

This can be written in a more compact way using

```kotlin
fun getAverage(nums: List<Int>) = if (nums.isEmpty()) 0.0 else (nums.sum().toDouble() / nums.size)
```

In that case, `getAverage(listOf())` will return `0.0`.

Alternatively, you could also make the result nullable and return `null` in that case:

```kotlin
fun getAverage(nums: List<Int>): Double?{
    return
        if (nums.isEmpty())
            null
        else
            (nums.sum().toDouble() / nums.size)
}
```

Comment: aaa ok, thank you, just out of curiosity, is there a way of making it in a 1 line command? I know that in java there is a short if option?

Comment: Well, you could skip the newlines and use `fun getAverage(nums: List<Int>) = if (nums.isEmpty()) 0.0 else (nums.sum().toDouble() / nums.size)` but I used multiple lines for clarity. As far as I know, Kotlin uses `if`/`else` instead of the ternary operator.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't knew that kotlin can recognize it like that too, thank you so much!